# Android Load Camera image as Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am using BitmapFactory.decodeFile to load Bitmaps of images into my application. However, the function returns null on large images (such as those from the camera). The filepath is definitely correct, I just can't figure out why it would return null. I tried supersampling, but it didn't seem to help.

Does anyone have any idea why it would do this or how I could more easily load images taken from the camera into a Bitmap?

Here's the code I am using:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String filePath){
    Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

    if(result == null){
        if(filePath.contains(".jpg") || filePath.contains(".png")){
            //This is the error that occurs when I attempt to load an image from the Camera DCIM folder or a large png I imported from my computer.
            Utils.Toast("Could not load file -- too big?"); 
        } else {
            Utils.Toast("Could not load file -- image file type is not supported");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you save camera images on SDCard ? Do all direcotries from path exist ?

Comment: Yes, the image is selected via a file browser so the path is certain to be correct. Other (smaller) images selected in the same folder work perfectly.

Comment: Can you please provide some piece of the code you are using?

Comment: Added the code I use. The path is correct (I'm using a file manager to choose it), just for some reason it returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to provide more info about your problem, such as a snippet of code that you are using. If you want to know when/why the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` method would return null, you can read directly its source code: http://casidiablo.in/BitmapFactory

For example, one of the reasons that causes `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` to return null is if there's a problem while openning the file. Curiously, the developers dont't log anything with such a problem... look at the comment *"do nothing. If the exception happened on open, bm will be null."*

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String pathName, Options opts) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(pathName);
        bm = decodeStream(stream, null, opts);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /*  do nothing.
            If the exception happened on open, bm will be null.
        */
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do nothing here
            }
        }
    }
    return bm;
}
```

As you can see, the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` does not work standalone... but it uses some other methods of the `BitmapFactory` class (for instance, `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`, `BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream`, `BitmapFactory.finishDecode`, etc.). The problem could be on one of those methods, so if I were you, I would try to read and understand how they work so that I could know in which cases they return null.

Comment: I just posted the code (probably while you were typing up the reply). I'll look into some of those methods like you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Well alright, I simply tried out the FileInputStream method instead and it actually does say that the file does not exist. Which is very strange considering there is a file there.

I'll keep fiddling.

Comment: Alright, it seems that the name of the file is the problem. I can actually load the images when I rename them to "image.jpg" rather than the name based on the timestamp of the photo. Thanks for the help. 

Of course I get an OOM exception now, but that's something else to handle.

Do you happen to know where I could find the source for the Gallery application (or any for that matter). I just need to figure out how they can get around the small heap size issue when loading and displaying large images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe inSampleSize option can help you?
[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)

Comment: I'm not getting an out of memory error, and superSampling didn't seem to help when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound obvious, but check that your filePath actually points to a file. You mention that you are using a file manager to select the image to open - it's possible that the file manager is returning a path to a content provider instead of a file.

There is a more robust way to open files using the ContentResolver class, which can open an InputStream to a content provider, file, or resource, without you needing to know in advance what kind of path you are passing it.

The only catch is that you need to pass a Uri object on the call to openInputStream() instead of a String.

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String filePath, Context c) {
    InputStream inStream;

    try {
        inStream = c.getContentResolver().openInputStream( Uri.parse(filePath) );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // handle file not found
    }

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
}
```

This also happens to be how the ImageView widget attempts to load images when you use its setImageURI method.